# Linear algebra reflection or rotation

Tags: matrices, reflection

I have a matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&-\frac12\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

How to define matrix is rotation or reflection?

Comment: Reflections have the property that they are their own inverse.

Comment: How does the matrix given relate to your question? Do you want a way to identify a rotation or reflection matrix or just want someone to tell you if your matrix is either? It's neither.

Answer (score 1):

Let have A as orthonormal matrix. If det(A)=1 then A is matrix of rotation, else if det(A)=-1 then A is matrix of reflection.
In your case matrix is not orthonormal, so it is not matrix of rotation nor matrix of reflection